# How can I multiply a matrix by a vector using JAMA?

Tags: java, vector, matrix, matrix-multiplication, jama

I'm trying to create a vector from an array of doubles. I then want to multiply this vector by a matrix. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Below is a really simple example that I would like to get working.

```
// Create the matrix (using JAMA)
Matrix a = new Matrix( [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] );

// Create a vector out of an array
...

// Multiply the vector by the matrix
...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is simple example of wanted operation:

```
double[][] array = {{1.,2.,3},{1.,2.,3.},{1.,2.,3.}}; 
Matrix a = new Matrix(array);   
Matrix b = new Matrix(new double[]{1., 1., 1.}, 1);     
Matrix c = b.times(a);  
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(c.getArray()));
```

Result:

```
[[3.0, 6.0, 9.0]]
```

In other words that is:

[image]

Comment: @Jon: Note that `Matrix` class API (http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/Jama/Matrix.html) is your friend to get more options :)

Comment: Hi! Sorry to be an idiot, but could you please give us an example of what happens when [1 1 1] is something like [2 5 3] instead?

Comment: @Joehot200: Matrix multiplication is fairly easy to learn by yourself, [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/alg2-matrices/matrix-multiplication-alg2/v/multiplying-a-matrix-by-a-matrix) should make your clear how to do it. Essentially you multiply "rows by columns", each product is then summed up and placed accordingly.

Comment: Right. Got it. Thanks. I can't believe that I had got all the way to learning sines, cosines, tangent, vector multiplication, etc, and yet never encountered matrix-vector multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use Matrix's arrayTimes method? A vector is just a 1 x n matrix (I think) so can't you initialize a second matrix with just 1 dimension and use arrayTimes?

```
Matrix a = new Matrix( [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] );
Matrix b = new Matrix( [[1,2,3]] ); // this is a vector
Matrix c = a.arrayTimes(b.transpose); // transpose so that the inner dimensions agree
```

This is what I think would work from reading the [doc](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/).

Comment: I just tried out your idea, however it seems to want the matrix dimensions to agree (ie. same number of rows and cols). However since the vector only has one row it throws an exception.

Comment: Ah my mistake! Multiplying matrices is a little tricky. It's not that both dimensions have to agree (that would be boring) it's just that the inner dimensions have to agree. You can still multiply a and b above, but you need to transpose b. I've edited the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work because the arguments of the constructor are not Java Syntax...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
double[][] vals = {{1.,2.,3},{4.,5.,6.},{7.,8.,10.}};
Matrix A = new Matrix(vals);
```

From http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/Jama/Matrix.html